# Cannot redirect to login method of auth controller when using tank auth in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using tank auth in codeigniter, i have folder structure like this, this one is working properly when I place it outside the Admin folder but i get 404 Page not found when i place it inside admin folder :

> Controller :

-

> Admin Folder
>
> ```
>  Auth.php
>  Admin.php
> ```
>
> Auth controller:

```
function index()
    {  
        if ($message = $this->session->flashdata('message')) {
            $this->load->view('auth/general_message', array('message' => $message));
        } else { 
            redirect('/auth/login/');

        }
    }
    /**
     * Login user on the site
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function login()
    {  
        if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {                                 // logged in
            redirect('');

        } elseif ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in(FALSE)) {                      // logged in, not activated
            redirect('/auth/send_again/');

        } else {  .....
```

I have given route something like this :

```
$route['admin'] = 'Admin/auth';
```

Answer (score 0):

The **redirect** statement in codeigniter sends the user to the specified web page using a redirect header statement.

Load URL helper in controller or model or you can load in `config/autoload.php` for global access, which is loaded in the following way:

In controller or Model like this:

> [$this->load->helper('url')](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html);

If you do not want to load in controller or model then load in `config/autoload.php`:

> $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

And call redirect function like this:

> redirect('/auth/login', 'refresh');

Answer (score 0):

add this at controller $this->load->helper('url');

Answer (score 0):

If your Auth controller path is  Controller/Admin/Auth
then use

```
redirect('admin/auth/login', 'refresh');
```

If it is Controller/Auth then use

```
redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
```

You need to load url helper in both case. i suggest you to autoload url helper in codeigniter project.